# DataPager in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, text, button, datapager

First is, I have asp:DataPager and inside I have:

```
<asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />
```

**Is possible change text in this button, and how?** Default is "First", but i need change language.

Second is, inside DataPager I have `<asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="4" />` but it isnt work without Javascript. **Can I make it work without Javascript and how pls?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change default text by changing [`FirstPageText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.nextpreviouspagerfield.firstpagetext.aspx) property.

Comment: @John - if this answer was helpful to you, don't forget to tag it as "Answer" and help out others that have your problem.